# Is it legal to use unquoted one-word strings in SCSS?

Tags: sass

I've noticed that SCSS doesn't complain when I use one-word strings without quoting them:

```
$hello: Hello;
@debug type-of($hello); // string
@debug $hello; // Hello
```

**Is this perfectly legal, or is there a catch?**

I wasn't able to find a hint in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly legal because regular CSS strings work that way as well.

Take a look at the documentation for [strings](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#sass-script-strings).

> CSS specifies two kinds of strings: those with quotes, such as "Lucida Grande" or 'http://sass-lang.com', and those without quotes, such as sans-serif or bold. SassScript recognizes both kinds, and in general if one kind of string is used in the Sass document, that kind of string will be used in the resulting CSS.